# EventMachine em-http-request image/png encoding issue?

Tags: jruby, eventmachine

I'm having an issue when downloading an image via em-http-request..

I want to be able to save the http body data to disk and then be able to
open the image normally, currently when saving the retrieved http body data
to disk via a binary write operation I get a corrupted image.

When I issue a get request to the target image I get back the following
truncated string in the body.

\357\277\275PNG\r\n\032\n\000\000\000\rIHDR\000\000\001h\000\000\000`\b\002

When using net:http to get the image I get the following truncated string

\211PNG\r\n\032\n\000\000\000\rIHDR\000\000\001h\000\000\000`\b\002\000\000\000\277\243\177[\000\000 \000IDATx\234\355]

When saving this string in binary mode, I can then open the Image fine.

So in this instance, em-http-request is handling the data in some way that net:http does 
not.

My questions,

1. I'm using ruby 1.8 is there an encoding issue here I'm not aware of?
2. When using em-http-request, do I have to decode transfer chunked encoding
   when downloading binary data?
3. Is there a particular request option I need to enable in em-http-request
   to snag binary data / images from servers?
4. After downloading the image data, What do I need to convert the em-http-request image data to a correct format for saving?

Been banging my head against the wall for about 12 hours on this one, any help 
would be greatly appreciated!!!

Also I'm running em-http-request with Latest Build of Eventmachine for Jruby.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this is due to a bug in http_parser.rb (0.5.3 java).  Specifically:

```
ret = callback_object.callMethod(context, "on_body", callback_object.getRuntime().newString(new String(data)));
```

Converting a byte array into a String using the default locale caused unpredictable behavior.  The fix was committed in `23a1fb5b5a0dc4506995a34ff149f450b8ceaf64` which used a ByteList:

```
ret = callback_object.callMethod(context, "on_body", RubyString.newString(runtime, new ByteList(data, UTF8Encoding.INSTANCE, false)));
```

Until there is a new release, I imagine you would have to build from master.

Answer (score 0):

I have image file downloading through eventmachine working in 1.9.3.    and it works fine.   In jruby 1.6.7 it fails

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'eventmachine'
require 'uuid'
require 'em-http-request'
EM.run do
  http = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new("http://.../image.png").get
  file = File.new("test_image.png", "wb")
  http.stream {|chunk|
    file.write chunk
  }
  http.errback {
    puts "error downloading image"
    file.close
    File.rm(file.path)
    EM.stop
  }
  http.callback {
    puts "success"
    file.close
    EM.stop
  }
end
```

Looks like a jruby bug.

I am using the following gems

```
em-http-request (1.0.2)
eventmachine (1.0.0.beta.4 java)
```